# Prometheus histograms and averaging sets with NaN values included

Tags: grafana, prometheus

In my app I have histograms setup for websocket ping times to every country, one histogram per country.  In Grafana I have a graph of the average ping time for several countries I'm most interested in via the following query

```
rate(country_ping_sum{country=~"AU|NZ|CA|GB|US",instance="$instance"}[15m]) / rate(country_ping_count{country=~"AU|NZ|CA|GB|US",instance="$instance"}[15m])
```

This works perfectly well.  I get a graph for each country.  Now I want to add to the same graph an average of all the other countries combined into one.

```
avg(rate(country_ping_sum{country!~"AU|NZ|CA|GB|US",instance="$instance"}[15m]) / rate(country_ping_count{country!~"AU|NZ|CA|GB|US",instance="$instance"}[15m]))
```

This fails.  When I try the query in the Prometheus query in the Prometheus console I get a value of NaN.  If I take the same query and remove the avg() function then I get a list of every matching country, some have values and some have NaN.  Many of the countries have a rate of 0 for both the sum and the count.  Clearly those divisions by 0 are amounting to NaN for those particular countries.

So my question, how can I filter out NaN values before passing to avg()?

Comment: `avg(country_ping_sum{country!~"AU|NZ|CA|GB|US",instance="$instance"} > 0)`. link -https://kuricat.com/articles/promql-process-nan-data-result-is-abnormal-mkziw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're effectively taking an average of an average, which is generally not correct.

Instead do a `sum` of each `rate`, and then divide to get the overall average.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for the quick response Brian!